# React.js Data Table “No data available in table”

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried all the options for inserting the following jquery code into different parts of the code, but it doesn't work.
The table is displayed without data.
File hierarchy: index.js -> mainGrid.js -> Table.js
I can't figure out where to insert jquery and its format for correct operation

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newsblog").DataTable();
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <!-- <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" /> -->
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.24/datatables.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript> -->
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://yastatic.net/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.24/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#newsblog").DataTable();
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Table.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import List from './List'

export default function Table() {
    const baseUrl="xxxxxx"
    const [data, setData]=useState([])

    
    const requestGet=async()=>{
        await axios.get(baseUrl)
        .then(response=>{
            setData(response.data)
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    
    useEffect(()=>{
        requestGet()
    },[])

    return (
        <div className="Table">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row mx-2 my-2">
                    <div className="col text-right">
                    </div>
                    <div className="col text-right"></div>
                    <div className="col text-right">
                         <List />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row mx-2 my-2">
                    <div className="col">
                        <table id="newsblog" className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" className="text-center align-middle">ID</th>
                                    <th scope="col" className="text-center align-middle">Ответственное лицо</th>
                                    <th scope="col" className="text-center align-middle">Кол-во загруженного материала, тонн</th>
                                    <th scope="col" className="text-center align-middle">Температура, Цельсия</th>
                                    <th scope="col" className="text-center align-middle">Время обработки, ч.</th>
                                    <th scope="col" className="text-center align-middle">Кол-во выгруженного материала, тонн</th>
                                    <th scope="col" className="text-center align-middle">Дата</th>
                                    <th scope="col" className="text-center align-middle">Номер печи</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {data.map(specs=>(
                                    <tr key={specs.id}>
                                        <td className="text-center align-middle p-1">{specs.id}</td>
                                        <td className="text-center align-middle p-1">{specs.resP_PERSON}</td>
                                        <td className="text-center align-middle p-1">{specs.loaD_MATERIALS}</td>
                                        <td className="text-center align-middle p-1">{specs.temperature}</td>
                                        <td className="text-center align-middle p-1">{specs.timing}</td>
                                        <td className="text-center align-middle p-1">{specs.unloaD_MATERIALS}</td>
                                        <td className="text-center align-middle p-1">{specs.reG_DATE}</td>
                                        <td className="text-center align-middle p-1">{specs.batterY_NUMB}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Mixing React and jQuery is a famously bad idea.  What's likely to happen is the React code will re-render parts of the DOM and the jQuery code won't have any references to the new elements.  Why not use one of the many, many React table rendering plugins/components?

Comment: Are you looking for the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)? Also, totally agree with the above comment.

Comment: I totally agree @David, but this is the fastest way I've found. I'm a complete novice, I don't know what to do. There is absolutely no time for alterations

Comment: use just one script for jquery and one for datatable. also you should place `jquery.min.js` before `datatable.min.js`

Comment: @Pipi: *"There is absolutely no time for alterations"* - You'll find that development proceeds much more quickly if you pick one framework and use it as designed, rather than trying to mix and match pieces from two fundamentally different frameworks. The more novice you are, the more you're going to spin your wheels on this and not get anywhere. You can certainly *try*, starting with [the above suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153865/react-js-data-table-no-data-available-in-table#comment118701118_67153865), but trying to mix these frameworks is a recipe for disaster.